# Displaying <alt> contents as text with LightBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, lightbox, lightbox2

ok, so I've been looking for a good lightbox plugin for a while now. And lightbox keeps popping up. But I need it to be able to display all the images with the  as text with the images. If there is a way can you please show me the light?? lol.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a data-title attribute if you want to show a caption.

```
<a href="images/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">Image #1</a>
```